# Shift the position of an element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const output = move(numbers, 3, -5);

console.log(output);

function move(array, index, offset) {
    const output = [...array];
    const element = output.splice(index, 1)[0];
    output.splice(index + offset, 0, element)
    return output;
}
```

The first line is an array of numbers.

At the second line, when calling the move function, we pass three arguments.

First, is the array itself called numbers. 
Secondly, the index of the number we are trying to move (in the example, we have index 3 so we are passing the number 4). 
Finally, we have the offset set to -5. The negative sign means we are moving the number to the left. The 5 means 5 positions.

But as you can see, we only have 3 positions to the left of the number 4 before reaching the beginning of the array. In this case, we have to go to the end of the array and count backwards. So, we are looking for a function which will turn the original array to [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 9].
As you can see, number 4 has shifted 3 positions to the left to reach the beginning of the array, then, 2 further positions from the end of the array.

A further example to clarify.

Let's say we write:

```
const output = move(numbers, 1, -4);
```

In this example, we want the number 2 from the array (index 1) to move 4 positions to the left. So, we should get [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 8, 9].

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: `move(numbers, 3, -5);` resutls in `[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9 ]` not `[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 9 ]`

Comment: lol the question is what changes do I have to make in the code to actually make it work?

Comment: right, so you're out by one - probably because `output.splice(index, 1)[0];` is shrinking output by one ... `output.splice(index + offset +1, 0, element)`

Comment: Good work Jaromanda X. It works. But I forgot to mention, it should also work when shifting to the right. So, if we pass 5 instead of -5, it should move 5 positions to the right.

Comment: @JaromandaX - In case the value of `index + offset` is less then `array.length`, then  `+ 1` will not be required

Comment: well, I wasn't providing a **solution** - I provided a **hint** to the problem - sometimes people can learn more from that last bit of solving the problem themselves :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - Point taken mate! :)

Comment: Sorry @NikhilAggarwal I wasn't being rude, I just sometimes give a hint if I believe the OP can have a light bulb moment :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - Well I know that for sure :) We had communicated many a times on this platform and I believe you have a good attitude towards fellow members. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cover the edge cases when the updated index is **less than 0** OR **greater than the array length**. You can try following

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function move(array, index, offset) {
    const output = [...array];
    const element = output.splice(index, 1)[0];
    let updatedIndex = index + offset;
    if(updatedIndex < 0) updatedIndex++; 
    else if (updatedIndex >= array.length) updatedIndex -= array.length;
    output.splice(updatedIndex, 0, element);
    return output;
}

console.log(move(numbers, 3, -5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `while` loop and iterating for the `Math.abs()` of the position you want to move to and then move in direction depending if parameter is positive or negative.

```js
function move(arr, i, p) {
  let left = p < 0,
    counter = Math.abs(p),
    newPos = i;
  while (--counter > -1) {
    newPos = (left ? (newPos - 1) : (newPos + 1));
    if (newPos == -1) newPos = arr.length - 1;
    if (newPos == arr.length) newPos = 0;
    if (counter == 0) arr.splice(newPos, 0, arr.splice(i, 1)[0])
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(move([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3, -5));
console.log(move([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 5, 5));
console.log(move([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1, -25));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function moveIndex(array, oIndex, nIndex) {
  var saved = []; // Stores the original values of the input array

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    saved[i] = array[i]; //Saving array's value

    if (oIndex < 0 || oIndex > array.length) {
      return array;
    }
    if (nIndex < 0 || nIndex > array.length) {
      return array;
    }
    //Checks if input is out of bounds

    if (oIndex < nIndex) {
      if (i >= oIndex) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
      }
      //Removes chosen Index

      if (i >= nIndex) {
        array[nIndex] = saved[oIndex]; //Moving chosen index
        if (i > nIndex) {
          array[i] = saved[i]; // Removing Undefined values
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (i >= nIndex) {
        array[i] = array[oIndex]; // Moving chosen index
        if (i > nIndex) {
          array[i] = saved[i - 1]; // saved[i -1] = [if(i >= moveTo)]
        }
      }
      saved[oIndex] = array[oIndex + 1]; //Removing chosen index
    }
  }

  return array; //Returning changed array
}
```

Comment: The goal of this code isn't to be efficient, it's to teach you how to think like a real programmer instead of relying on built-in features and methods. If you want to master coding, you need to be able to solve problems on your own.